# Restar varlores de un array con el ultimo valor de otro array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Necesito agregarle a esta resta `tamaño -= parseInt(distanciaCentroUltimo[n]);` el ultimo elemento de `otroArray` que es 970 y dividirlo por 2
**NOTA**: el array que se llama otroArray puede crecer asi que no siempre sera 970 el ultimo elemento.

Me explico: esta resta `tamaño -= parseInt(distanciaCentroUltimo[n])` me da un resultado de `tamaño = 895`, entonces a ese `895` debo restarlo con el ultimo valor de `otrosarray` y dividirlo por `2` el cula me debe dar un resultado final de tamaño de `410`.

La operacion matematica seria asi: `4500-890-930-885-900 = 895 - 970 /2 = 410`

Esto es lo que tengo por el momento.

```
var distanciaCentroUltimo = [890,930,885,900];
var tamaño = 4500;
var otroArray = [920,850,970]; 

for ( n in distanciaCentroUltimo) {
    tamaño -= parseInt(distanciaCentroUltimo[n]);
};

console.log(tamaño);
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres por *agregar*? ¿sumar? osea, deseas sumarle a `parseInt(distanciaCentroUltimo[n])` el último elemento de `otroArray` y a ese total dividirlo entre 2?

Comment: Me explico: esta resta `tamaño -= parseInt(distanciaCentroUltimo[n])` me da un resultado de tamaño = 895, entonces a ese 895 debo restarlo con el ultimo valor de `otrosarray` y dividirlo por 2 el cula me debe dar un resultado final de tamaño de 410.

Comment: ¿Y ese 410 debes asignarlo nuevamente a tamaño?

Comment: Si el log me mostraria que tamaño es igual a 410.

Comment: La operacion matematica seria asi: `4500-890-930-885-900 = 895 - 970 /2 = 410`

Comment: Eduardo por favor añadir una mejor explicación a su pregunta *(y no en comentarios)* así como está planteada no se logra comprender que desea realizar ni que resultado desea obtener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basado en tu comentario:

> La operacion matematica seria asi: 4500-890-930-885-900 = 895 - 970 /2 = 410

Solo necesitas obtener el último elemento de `otroArray` y dividirlo entre 2 para restar este resultado al tamaño. Puedes hacerlo mediante `otroArray[otroArray.length - 1]` o mediante `slice`. En términos de rendimiento, la primera forma es sutilmente más rápida que la segunda:

```js
var distanciaCentroUltimo = [890, 930, 885, 900];
var tamanio = 4500;
var otroArray = [920, 850, 970];

for (let distancia of distanciaCentroUltimo) {
  tamanio -= parseInt(distancia);
}

tamanio -= otroArray.slice(-1)[0] / 2;
console.info(tamanio)
```

También puedes ahorrarte el for y usar `reduce`:

```js
var distanciaCentroUltimo = [890, 930, 885, 900];
var tamanio = 4500;
var otroArray = [920, 850, 970];

tamanio -= distanciaCentroUltimo.reduce(function(acc, dist) {
  return acc + dist;
})

tamanio -= otroArray.slice(-1)[0] / 2;
console.info(tamanio)
```